# css less bug for nesting header tags within class selector

Tags: html, css

Given the LESS syntax for css nesting as follows

```
.center {
  h2 {
    text-align : center;
  }
  h3 {
    color:red;
  }
}
```

When checked with online compiler, got it as expected:-

```
.center h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.center h3 {
  color: red;
}
```

But for the less syntax doesn't work as given above. Whereas, if given as mentioned in 2nd (the compiled one) directly, then it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/s0hajL4m/

https://jsfiddle.net/co60cdus/

This the html i used

```
  <body>
   <div class="center">
    <h2>Welcome Users</h2>
    <h3>Login</h3>
  </body>
```

Is there any css rule for this scenario? Or is this a bug?

Comment: You've not included the Less compiler in the fiddle that is using Less syntax. Less compiles into CSS when the compiler is used but without the compilation nested Less classes is not valid CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers don't support LESS.

You've just dumped your LESS in a box that JSFiddle marks "CSS". JSFiddle then builds a webpage and tells the browser it is CSS. Since it is not CSS, browsers hit syntax errors and don't parse it the way you expect.

You need to [compile it to CSS](http://lesscss.org/#using-less-command-line-usage) and then include the CSS in the page.

Alternatively (and not recommended because it is inefficient and [less reliable](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html)) you can [include JavaScript](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage) to read the LESS and generate CSS on the fly.